# Get API call typescript with Angular

Tags: typescript, rest, api, ionic4, angular8

I'm facing to a problem concerning the call to my API Data.
When I initialize my function into ngOnit(). I cannot display any data.

**user.service.ts**

```
  getUser(id): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/users/' + id)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`User fetched: ${id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<User[]>(`Get user id=${id}`))
      );
  }
```

**user.page.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from "../services/user.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.page.scss'],
})
export class UsersPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getUserList()
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess, you will need to assign (or to subscribe) your fetched data to some variable in your user.page.ts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your services returns an observable, you will need to subscribe to it in the `ngOnInit` function.
Assign the result to a public variable and use that in your HTML to display data.

```
public users: User[] = [];
ngOnInit () {
   this.userService.getUserList().subscribe ( users => {
       this.users = users;
       console.log ( this.users);
   });
}
```